# How to get count of columns using single queries

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in my database from which i want to fetch data on the basis of count

my table name is `syncbill` and columns are `Cancelled` and `Noofprints`  i am trying to write a query to fetch the count of `cancelled` and count of `noofbills` using single query

- For cancelled i want to fetch count of cancelled where cancelled<>`Y`
- for Noofprints i want to fetch count of `noofprints` where noofprints>1

I am using

```
select count(CANCELLED) as canceledbill,count(NOOFPRINTS) as duplicatebill 
from syncbill where CANCELLED<>'Y' and NOOFPRINTS>1`
```

this query but it is giving me the same no of counts for both

[image: This is my data base table <code>syncbill</code>]

any one out-here please guide me

Comment: Got to go. Query SQL SUM CASE for an example of how to use a case statement to select 0 or 1 for each value and then sum them.

Comment: You can use a ‘sum(case when cancelled<>'Y' then 1 else 0 end), sum(case when noofprints>1 then 1 else 0 end)’

Comment: @DaleBurrell i am using my sql 5.1

Comment: @JaimeDrq can you help me with the edit in my query i have posted please

Comment: @DaleBurrell  mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `sum()` with case expreseeion

```
SELECT
    sum(CASE WHEN CANCELLED <> 'Y' THEN 1 else 0 END) AS canceledbill,
    sum(CASE WHEN NOOFPRINTS > 1 THEN 1  else 0 END)   AS duplicatebill
FROM table_name;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(CASE WHEN CANCELLED <> 'Y' THEN 1 END) AS cancelledbill,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN NOOFPRINTS > 1 THEN 1 END)   AS duplicatebill
FROM yourTable;
```

If you are actually using MySQL, then the above can be simplified to this:

```
SELECT
    SUM(CANCELLED <> 'Y') AS cancelledbill,
    SUM(NOOFPRINTS > 1)   AS duplicatebill
FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: You have to sum not count

Answer (score 0):

USE `CASE WHEN` Expression

```
select 
    sum(case when CANCELLED <> 'Y' then 1 else 0 end) AS cancelledbill,
    sum(case when NOOFPRINTS > 1 then 1 else 0 end)   AS duplicatebill
FROM tablename;
```

Comment: have you executed this? and could you please add your expected output in your question @viveksingh

Comment: @fa06 it is giving cancelled bill as 0

Comment: You need else conditions in your sums.